# GPRS Setting in J2ME

Tags: java-me, httpconnection

I am creating a `Java ME` application to connect to server. My problem in `HttpConnection` setting issue. how can i dynamically configure gprs setting in my application.Opera mini browser dynamically get connection setting. how can i do same in my application ?

Comment: Whtat problem you facing in httpconnection setting?

Comment: in Opera mini browser internet is working fine..but in my application internet is not working.internet setting issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to get connections for your applications because of the following reasons

1. HttpConnetion gets the default settings for java . trying to load this setting would involve you developing specific application version for each phone
2. Opera mini has different arrangement with most telecom to force all connection via WAP gateway because they require MSISDN and IMSI information .. Am sure you don't want to go this wrote
3. Blackberry has option to connect via BIS, BES , Wifi or WAP  ... this is very straight forward but am sure your application is not for blackberry

**4 reason your app might not be working**

1. Some phone required you to specify default connection for java phone
2. The network sometime has more than one setting .. check the one your browser is using and set it as default for all connection
3. Sometimes when phone have been used with multiple SIMS ... the configuration might not be correct .
4. Ensure you have enable for data access because your Opera Mini might be using a diffident billing option based on most of their custom arrangement

I hope this helps

Thanks
:)